# Remove rows where column value type is string Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe. One of my columns should only be floats. When I try to convert that column to floats, I'm alerted that there are strings in there. I'd like to delete all rows where values in this column are strings...

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Use `convert_objects` with param `convert_numeric=True` this will coerce any non numeric values to `NaN`:

```
In [24]:

df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [0.1,0.5,'jasdh', 9.0]})
df
Out[24]:
       a
0    0.1
1    0.5
2  jasdh
3      9
In [27]:

df.convert_objects(convert_numeric=True)
Out[27]:
     a
0  0.1
1  0.5
2  NaN
3  9.0
In [29]:
```

You can then drop them:

```
df.convert_objects(convert_numeric=True).dropna()
Out[29]:
     a
0  0.1
1  0.5
3  9.0
```

**UPDATE**

Since version `0.17.0` this method is now [deprecated](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew.html#whatsnew-0170-deprecations) and you need to use [`to_numeric`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_numeric.html) unfortunately this operates on a `Series` rather than a whole df so the equivalent code is now:

```
df.apply(lambda x: pd.to_numeric(x, errors='coerce')).dropna()
```

Comment: Thanks for this! My dataframe has multiple columns. Some columns need to have strings. For instance, I have a column 'name' and a column 'age'. The column 'age' needs to be numeric. I tried: df.age.convert_objects(convert_numeric=True) and got 'Series' object has no attribute 'convert_objects'.

Comment: You need to do `df[['age']].convert_objects(convert_numeric=True)` in that case

Comment: Oh I see, so [['age']] picks out a the column in df. Very helpful. However, I'm getting a TypeError: convert_objects() got an unexpected keyword argument 'convert_numeric. I just checked the documentation and 'convert_numeric = True' is the correct argument. Thoughts?

Comment: Okay, I think that my pandas is out of date. Updating now.

Comment: Hi.  I get a 'convert_objects deprecated' FutureWarning when trying to use this.  Any suggestions?

Comment: @magicsword that was deprecated some time ago `pandas` moves quickly, it's recommended to use `pd.to_numeric` nowadays so the above becomes `df.apply(lambda x: pd.to_numeric(x, errors='coerce')).dropna()`

Answer (score 6):

> One of my columns should only be floats. I'd like to delete all rows
>   where values in this column are strings

You can convert your series to numeric via [`pd.to_numeric`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_numeric.html) and then use [`pd.Series.notnull`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.notnull.html). Conversion to `float` is required as a separate step to avoid your series reverting to `object` dtype.

```
# Data from @EdChum

df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [0.1, 0.5, 'jasdh', 9.0]})

res = df[pd.to_numeric(df['a'], errors='coerce').notnull()]
res['a'] = res['a'].astype(float)

print(res)

     a
0  0.1
1  0.5
3  9.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Assume your data frame is `df` and you wanted to ensure that all data in one of the column of your data frame is numeric in specific `pandas dtype`, e.g `float`:

```
df[df.columns[n]] = df[df.columns[n]].apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce').fillna(0).astype(float).dropna()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find the data type of a column from the `dtype.kind` attribute. Something like `df[col].dtype.kind`. See [the numpy docs](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.dtype.kind.html) for more details. Transpose the dataframe to go from indices to columns.