# Pandas delete all rows that are not a 'datetime' type

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I've got a large file with login information for a list of users. The problem is that the file includes other information in the `Date` column. I would like to remove all rows that are not of type `datetime` in the `Date` column. My data resembles

`df`:

| Name | Date |
| --- | --- |
| name_1 | 2012-07-12 22:20:00 |
| name_1 | 2012-07-16 22:19:00 |
| name_1 | 2013-12-16 17:50:00 |
| name_1 | 4345 # type = 'int' |
| ... | # type = 'float' |
| name_2 | 2010-01-11 19:54:00 |
| name_2 | 2010-02-06 12:10:00 |
| ... |  |
| name_2 | 2012-07-18 22:12:00 |
| name_2 | 4521 |
| ... |  |
| name_5423 | 2013-11-23 10:21:00 |
| ... |  |
| name_5423 | 7532 |

I've tried modifying the solution to

[Finding non-numeric rows in dataframe in pandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21771133/finding-non-numeric-rows-in-dataframe-in-pandas)

[Remove rows where column value type is string Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26771471/remove-rows-where-column-value-type-is-string-pandas)

and [How-should-I-delete-rows-from-a-DataFrame-in-Python-Pandas](https://www.quora.com/How-should-I-delete-rows-from-a-DataFrame-in-Python-Pandas)

to fit my needs.

The problem is that whenever I attempt the change I either get an error or the entire dataframe gets deleted

Comment: shouldn't `df = df[df['Date'].apply(lambda x: type(x) == datetime.datetime)]` work

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Use `pd.to_datetime` with parameter `errors='coerce'` to make non-dates into `NaT` null values.  Then you can drop those rows

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], errors='coerce')
df = df.dropna(subset=['Date'])

df
```

[image]

Comment: This is helpful.  Incidentally, it's now "errors='ignore' on more modern pandas (I'm on 0.24).  Otherwise, thumbs up!

Comment: On pandas 1.1.1 it's still "coerce" to get NaN values (https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html)

Answer (score 1):

We could use the same method as @piRSquared to make non-datetime values to NaT values and use `notna` (i.e. select non-NaN values) to create a boolean Series and filter `df`:

```
df = df[pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], errors='coerce').notna()]
```

Note that unlike @piRSquared's method, it doesn't modify the dtype of "Date" column. Whether it's a desirable behavior or not is up to you.

Output:

```
         Name                 Date
0      name_1  2012-07-12 22:20:00
1      name_1  2012-07-16 22:19:00
2      name_1  2013-12-16 17:50:00
5      name_2  2010-01-11 19:54:00
6      name_2  2010-02-06 12:10:00
8      name_2  2012-07-18 22:12:00
11  name_5423  2013-11-23 10:21:00
```