# Drop rows in dataframe where column X value is a datetime

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I need to drop rows where column X value is a datetime.

I have tried this

```
from pandas.api.types import is_datetime64_any_dtype as is_datetime
indexNames = df[is_datetime(df['Column X'])].index
df.drop(indexNames, inplace=True)
```

but it returns

> KeyError: False

This below doesnt work either (no error)

```
indexNames = df[df['Column X'] == is_datetime(df['Column X'])].index
```

I have still values like this datetime.datetime(2016, 6, 29, 8, 24, 19)

Ive found a related question but inversed [Pandas delete all rows that are not a 'datetime' type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39604094/pandas-delete-all-rows-that-are-not-a-datetime-type)

have you any idea please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) with `errors='coerce'` for convert non datetimelike to `NaN`s, so filter by [`Series.isna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isna.html) in [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df = df[pd.to_datetime(df['Column X'], errors='coerce').isna()]
```

But sometimes pandas recognise some integers like `2000` for datetimes, so if possible more accurate is specify format of datetimes, e.g. here `YYYY-MM-DD`:

```
df = df[pd.to_datetime(df['Column X'], errors='coerce', format='%Y-%m-%d').isna()]
```

Comment: Thanks, this is something like that, but th opposite, how to drop datetimes ? This drops all but datetimes

Comment: @TTeaTie - Use `isna` here