# Remove all rows that meet regex condition

Tags: python, regex, pandas

trying to teach myself pandas.. and playing around with different dtypes

I have a df as follows

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID':[0,2,"bike","cake"], 'Course':['Test','Math','Store','History'] })
print(df)
    ID  Course
0   0   Test
1   2   Math
2   bike    Store
3   cake    History
```

the dtype of ID is of course an object. What I want to do is remove any rows in the DF if the ID has a string in it.

I thought this would be as simple as..

```
df.ID.filter(regex='[\w]*')
```

but this returns everything, is there a sure fire method for dealing with such things?

Comment: Related / possible duplicate: [Remove rows where column value type is string Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26771471/remove-rows-where-column-value-type-is-string-pandas)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can using `to_numeric`

```
df[pd.to_numeric(df.ID,errors='coerce').notnull()]
Out[450]: 
  Course ID
0   Test  0
1   Math  2
```

Answer (score 5):

Another option is to convert the column to string and use `str.match`:

```
print(df[df['ID'].astype(str).str.match("\d+")])
#  Course ID
#0   Test  0
#1   Math  2
```

Your code does not work, because as stated in the docs for [`pandas.DataFrame.filter`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html):

> Note that this routine does not filter a dataframe on its contents. The filter is applied to the labels of the index.

Answer (score 5):

[Wen's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52230026/3483203) is the correct (and fastest) way to solve this, but to explain why your regular expression doesn't work, you have to understand what `\w` means.

`\w` matches any word character, which includes `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`.  So what you're currently matching *includes* digits, so everything is matched.  A valid regular expression approach would be:

```
df.loc[df.ID.astype(str).str.match(r'\d+')]
```

```
  ID Course
0  0   Test
1  2   Math
```

The second issue is your use of `filter`.  It isn't filtering your `ID` row, it is filtering your index.  A valid solution using `filter` would be as follows:

```
df.set_index('ID').filter(regex=r'^\d+$', axis=0)
```

```
   Course
ID
0    Test
2    Math
```

Comment: Thanks! all the solutions work for me, I'm not really sure which one to green tick..? what would you recommend my good sir? the /w was extremely informative I didn't know filter worked on index exclusively.

Comment: Wen's answer is the correct way to do this.  I'd recommend that one, but glad that you found all the answers helpful :)